# Script to enforce backup retention policy

Tags: powershell, string-comparison

I have a need for a script that can look at our backup folders (we take full backups of machines) and ensure that we never store more than the two most recent backups for each computer. I am currently working on a powershell loop that should compare each file name to every other file in the backup folder. Each machine has multiple backup files that can be identified by a matching prefix and a unique ID number separated by a delimiting character.

prefix = machine name and unique ID denotes each backup.

I am working on setting up the outer loop and running into a wall. I am storing the list of files to be checked in `$array`.

I have a nested for loop that I want to have check each file against every other file in the array. I have a query that should rebuild the array and exclude the current reference file each iteration.

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt 5; $i++) {
```

$array = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Aaron.Trujillo\Desktop\test
$array = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Aaron.Trujillo\Desktop\test                -Exclude $array[$i]

```
for ($j=0; $j -lt 5; $j++){ 
    Write-Host "i: $i  j: $j"
    Write-Host "Array i: $($array[$i].name)  Array j: $($array[$j].name)"

    if($array[$i].name -ne $array[$j].name)
    {
        Write-Host "truthval=false"
        $truthval="false"
    } 

    else
    {
        Write-Host "truthval=true"
        $truthval = "true"
    } 
}
```

}

I was expecting this loop to compare the first five files in the array against each other (excluding the current reference file) and change the variable for each file, but for some reason the reference file isn't getting excluded.

Something must be wrong with the logic, but I'm struggling to spot it.

Comment: if  was doing what you seem to be doing ... i would use `Group-Object`. you can use calculated properties for grouping just as you can use calculated props with `Select-Object`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several flaws with your code.

1. As `$array` is presumably populated by a `Get-ChildItem` (which on ntfs formatted drives returns a **sorted** output) the nested loops aren't neccessary at all.
   When iterating with one for simply compare with the predessor/follower `index +/- 1`.
2. As Names include per your description an ID, they are always different. So you've to split the name at the nebulous delimiter and check if the machine name is the same.
3. your `if` command doesn't emit anything, it just overwrites the same variable on every iteration.

With @Lee_Dailey's good idea of grouping you can split the names on the fly and check the count per group, sort files per group by LastWriteTime and only keep the newest 2.

So given a hypothetical tree of files

```
> tree /F
A:.
└───Backup
        Alpha_8.bak
        Bravo_2.bak
        Bravo_5.bak
        Bravo_6.bak
        Bravo_7.bak
        Bravo_9.bak
        Charlie_1.bak
        Charlie_10.bak
        Charlie_3.bak
        Charlie_4.bak
```

this small script:

```
$BackupDir = 'A:\Backup'
$Delim     = '_'

Get-ChildItem -Path $BackupDir -File | 
  Group-Object {($_.BaseName -split $Delim)[0]}
```

yields:

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    1 Alpha                     {Alpha_8.bak}
    5 Bravo                     {Bravo_2.bak, Bravo_5.bak, Bravo_6.bak, Bravo_7.bak...}
    4 Charlie                   {Charlie_1.bak, Charlie_10.bak, Charlie_3.bak, Charlie_4.bak}
```

You can then iterate the groups and delete files per group by whatever means,
for example delete all but the 2 newest (defined per LastWriteTime) files per machine:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $BackupDir -File | 
  Group-Object {($_.BaseName -split $Delim)[0]} | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort LastWriteTime -Desc | Select -skip 2 | Remove-Item -WhatIf
  }
```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`

Comment: Thank you for this. As I'm sure you can tell, I'm still new to powershell. Would you mind explaining how the second line of your code works? Also, are there any resources you'd recommend on learning powershell? I'm just starting you use it, but I'm definitely seeing that will essential for me to learn.

Comment: While I bought 2 books and read them (not very thorough I've to attest) I learned the most from reading **and** helping here on [SO], Start by reading the [tag:powershell] tag [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/powershell/info)

Comment: See also: [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/), [ss64.com/ps](http://ss64.com/ps/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the brackets around the `$array[$j.name]` i.e. it should be:

```
if($array[$i].name -ne $array[$j].name)
```

---

Edit:

For troubleshooting try manually outputting your information:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt 5; $i++) { 

    for ($j=$i+1; $j -lt 5; $j++){ 
        Write-Host "i: $i  j: $j"
        Write-Host "Array i: $($array[$i].name)  Array j: $($array[$j].name)"

        if($array[$i].name -ne $array[$j].name)
        {
            Write-Host "truthval=false"
            $truthval="false"
        } 

        else
        {
            Write-Host "truthval=true"
            $truthval = "true"
        } 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I fix that and the script runs without errors. There's definitely something wrong with the logic was well though. The $truthval variable isn't updating at all.

Comment: I think that you have to change how you update `$truthval` because as it's written, `$truthval` will always be the value of the very last comparison (i.e. you keep overwriting it in the loop)

Comment: I know that I need to do that, but currently the variable contains the value "null" which is what I initialized it with. Which means it's not getting updated at all.

Comment: @amatthew382 Try the code in the edits above to see what's going on.

Comment: It looks like the code is changing the $truthval, but once the loop exits $truthval is still evaluated as null. Also, as the loop progresses the reference file is getting compared to fewer files incrementally.

Comment: Are you running it in a script or inside a function? because then you have to deal with scopes. I was able to run it in the console and get a value.

Comment: I'm running it inside a script, I assumed that the script file would run in the console the same as manually typing it.

Comment: So when it's run in the terminal I'm getting the correct values. Is this because the variables created in the script are only valid as the script runs?

Comment: Correct. When you run scripts they run inside their own scope, and you can't access the variables outside the script. The one exception is if you [dot source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-6#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) the script e.g. `. myscript.ps1` then it runs the script inside the local scope i.e. as if you copied and pasted the code into the console.